# FLASK SQLAlchemy: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

There are many other answers on this topic but none have helped.

I am simply trying to add an item to my database.

Database setup

```
class Client(db.Model, CommonFields):
    __tablename__ = "client"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "metadata"}

    name = db.Column(db.String)
    client_id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey("metadata.clientid"))
    roles = db.relationship("Role", secondary=client_roles)
```

Service

```
def addClient(
    name: str,
    client: int,
    roles: typing.List[Role],
):
    client = Client(
        name=name,
        client=client, 
        roles=roles
    ).insert()

    return client
```

#fails on insert

```
def insert(self):
        with db_session_manager(
            message_if_fails=f"Failed adding"
        ):
            db.session.add(self)
```

How do I fix 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'?

Here is the full error

```
File "/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 3098, in cascade_iterator
    queue = deque(
  File "/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1938, in cascade_iterator
    tuples = state.manager[self.key].impl.get_all_pending(state, dict_)
  File "/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1153, in get_all_pending
    current_states = [
  File "/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1154, in <listcomp>
    ((c is not None) and instance_state(c) or None, c)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
```

Comment: I guess this is a mypy error? Which part of your code does the error refer to?

Comment: @evanstjabadi it fails in the insert so essentially, `db.session.add(self)`

Comment: It would be useful to see an example of what you're passing to `addClient()` .

Comment: @JonathanCiapetti `client.addClient(name, client, roles)`

Comment: At a guess, you are adding roles as strings rather than Role instances.

Comment: `roles=db.session.query(Roles).filter(role_name.in_(roles).all()`. Then pass this `roles` objects into your `client = Client(
        name=name,
        client=client, 
        roles=roles
    ).insert()`

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of potential issues that may be getting in your way:

1. In `addClient()` you are accepting a value for client then passing it to `Client()` as `client=client,` when you probably mean `client_id=client,` since the Client class has `client_id` not `client`.
2. Your `AttributeError` exception I believe is indicating that your `roles` parameter got one or more strings instead of `Role` type objects, which would have the `_sa_instance_state` attribute that it is (correctly) complaining is missing on type `str`. To correct this, you may need to take the role strings and look up (or create) the corresponding Role records, and pass those ORM objects instead.